# Is it possible to change a JS String Variable in script.js file from a WordPress template PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a issue that I want to solve but do not fully understand on how to approach it and wondering if anybody on here knows a way at all.

In my WordPress theme I have a script.js file located in a JS Folder which has a script for loading an Instagram feed on page load.

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
 $.instagramFeed({
'username': 'usernamehere',
'container': "#instagram-feed-demo",
'display_profile': false,
'display_biography': false,
'display_igtv': false,
'items': 9,
'items_per_row': 3,
  'styling': false
 });
});
```

In my WordPress single page template I want to populate the username string by using a custom field but if I move the script into the template in a script tag it does not work but works fine in the script.js file.

Does anybody know a way to populate the string from the single template at all ?

Comment: The most correct way, I think, would be to use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/ to output a JS variable from within your template, and then have you external script use that variable in the place of the currently static text.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the reply i really appreciate it, I am not quite sure I understand this way and how to right it. any guidance ?

Comment: https://digwp.com/2019/07/better-inline-script/ has a more in-depth explanation, and also explains what the main differences between `wp_add_inline_script` and `wp_localize_script` are. Decide based on that, which works better for your use case.

Comment: so on my page template I can tell it to do the function passing the variable in then hat outputs to the scrip.js file I have, do i have that correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly what you need but you might check the template where it loads the script.js file (using a `wp_enqueue_script` function) and add another call to `wp_localize_script` function using the same handler name and pass it an array of variables to be available for the javascript.

Example:

```
wp_enqueue_script('script-handler', 'url to the script.js file', []);
wp_localize_script('script-handler', 'jsObjectName', [
  'username' => $usernamehere,
]);
```

The js object `jsObjectName` created with the `wp_localize_script` function will precede the call for the script.js file, making it's values available for use in the script.

Now change the Instegram code to something like this:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
  $.instagramFeed({
    'username': jsObjectName.username,
    'container': "#instagram-feed-demo",
    'display_profile': false,
    'display_biography': false,
    'display_igtv': false,
    'items': 9,
    'items_per_row': 3,
    'styling': false
  });
```

});

Comment: I believe it loads using either wp_head(); or get_header(); doesn't it

Comment: does the wp_localize_script go in the template or functions.php

Comment: I have added the localise script to the functions underneath where I enqueue my script.js but on my template how do I set the $usernamehere variable as I do $usernamehere = echo the_field('instagram_handle'); and it says its undefined ? I need the page to populate the username string from a custom field i've set for that post  type

Comment: Assuming you are using "Advanced Custom Fields" plugin, you need to use the `get_field` function as follows: `'username' => get_field('instagram_handle)`.

Comment: @JoeCold did you get it working "inside" a template page? Not sure why the answerer didn't understand the basic question.